# .NET Core create new product - the result is always Product {Id: -2147482647}

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm using .NET Core 5, I've created many other things and it worked and so was the time before I created a `Product`. But now when I go back and create a new `Product`, I always get `error null` and when I debug I see `Product ID {Id: -2147482647}`. So what error is this?

I tried searching but couldn't come up with something similar to what I'm having

```
public ProductTrademarkViewModel CreateProduct(ProductTrademarkViewModel productTrademarkViewModel)
    {
        var checkExists = _dbContext.Products.Include(p => p.Trademark).Where(p => p.ProductName == productTrademarkViewModel.Product.ProductName
        && p.Trademark.Id == productTrademarkViewModel.Product.TrademarkId);
        if (checkExists.Any())
        {
            //
        }
        else
        {
            var productResult = _dbContext.Products.Add(productTrademarkViewModel.Product);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            return null;
        }
        var newProduct = new ProductTrademarkViewModel
        {
            Product = productTrademarkViewModel.Product,
            Trademarks = _dbContext.Trademarks.ToList(),
            StatusMessage = "Error: " + _dbContext.Trademarks.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Id == productTrademarkViewModel.Product.TrademarkId).TrademarkName.ToString()
        };
        return newProduct;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using efcore or nhibernate? The id you're seeing, is that before or after the `DbContext.SaveChanges()`? If before: that's normal.

Comment: @Pieterjan I using EFcore, `var productResult = _dbContext.Products.Add(productTrademarkViewModel.Product);` 
here is the code before `SaveChange()`, when debug points it will show the Id that I am seeing. The final result that I get is null

Comment: Can you show the specific errors reported on VS?